# IntelliJ Spring Facet bean discovery on transitive dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I noticed that IntelliJ no longer discovers Spring Beans from transitive dependencies. I'm pretty sure this used to work but can't pin down the exact version this stopped working.

Given a Spring Boot Application with 3 Gradle Projects:

- Gradle Project `sub2` containing:

  - Spring Service `Sub2Bean`
- Gradle Project `sub1` depending on `sub2` containing:

  - Spring Service `Sub1Bean` injecting `Sub2Bean`
- Root Project depending on `sub1`

  - containing `SpringbootApplication`
  - a `RestController` injecting `Sub1Bean`

```
Root project 'sandbox-springboot'
+--- Project ':sub1'
\--- Project ':sub2'
```

At runtime this works as expected. But unfortunately when looking at `Sub1Bean` in IntelliJ it doesn't find the `Sub2Bean` saying `"Could not Autowire. No Beans of 'Sub2Bean' type found."`

When I explicitly add the `sub2` gradle dependency to the main gradle project IntelliJ discovers the bean and correctly shows the Spring Gutter Icon for the injected `Sub2Bean`.

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to pickup on transitive Spring Beans or do we need to explicitly list every dependency in the gradle project containing the `SpringBootApplication`?

**Withouth explicit dependency: bean is not discovered**

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":sub1"))
}
```

[image]

**With explicit dependency: bean is discovered**

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":sub1"))
    implementation(project(":sub2"))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which is expected. You are using `implementation` scope, which means this isn't exposed as transitive dependency. So something using `sub2` doesn't know about `sub1` because it is an implementation detail. If you want it to be exposed you would need to use `api` instead of `implementation` or, as you did now, add it as an explicit dependency.

Comment: Since our root project only contains the SpringbootApplication and nothing else it could be done. As all the other projects would still profit from the hidden transitive dependencies. But it feels weird to add all dependencies explicitly _just_ to please IntelliJ.

Comment: It isn't to please Intellij, that is how the Gradle dependency model works.

Comment: But as you see in the example above, Gradle is completely happy. The controller only injects beans from the gradle projects it depends on `sub1` and the bean `Sub1Bean` then injects beans from `sub2` which the controller cannot inject as it's in `implementation` scope this is the expected behaviour as you mention. *BUT* the problem is that while the compiler is happy and this all works, also at runtime: the IntelliJ Spring Facet is not and wrongly states that there is no `Sub2Bean` to Autowire... when looking at the `Sub1Bean` even though it's part of the Spring Context.

Comment: I think you could create an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA to report this problem.

Comment: I created a YouTrack issue for those interessted in following: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-313869/IntelliJ-Spring-Facet-bean-discovery-on-transitive-dependencies